# Are there nonrestricted finite-ranged functions without asymptotic or limiting behavior? If so, what kinds?

Tags: limits, functions, asymptotics

$x∈ℝ\:↦\:y=:\text{sin}(x)$ has no limit but is asymptotic about the constant $y=0$;

$x∈ℝ\:↦\:y=:\text{tan}(x)$ has has periodic limiting ($n∈ℤ:\text{As }x\stackrel{⟨-,+⟩}{→}πn\text{,}\:\: y→⟨+,-⟩∞$);

$x∈ℝ\:↦\:y=:x^2$ is not asymptotic about any [simpler ]equation and hasn't strict-limit, but $\text{as }x→±∞\text{,}\:\: y→∞$ (has unbounded growth, i.e. infinite range).

Are there any functional relations yielding finite-valued real outputs that are absent of both types of guaranteed behaviors (limiting or algebraic asymptotic)? $\:${What kinds?}

Comment: This isn't really a well-defined question ("asymptotic about a constant" hasn't been defined), but what about $x^2\sin x$? or $e^{\sin x} + e^{\sin \sqrt x}$?

Comment: @Greg Martin ~~The first one appears to go to infinity at intervals. The latter might match fit. Does it have asymptotic behavior (for large |x|)? On the graph it looks like maybe logarithmic.

Comment: Again, "go to infinity at intervals" is a phrase that doesn't have a definition; so it's very hard to understand precisely what kind of function you're looking for. The latter function is trivially bounded between $2/e$ and $2e$.

Comment: @Greg Martin  ~~a bound between two constants is fine if no middle tendency is determinable within the set of possible range values (e.g. weighted toward a certain value such as a/g/h  mean like with $\cos x$).